# Run a simple shell script before running CMD command in Dockerfile

Tags: shell, docker, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile and the last command is

`CMD ["/opt/startup.sh"]`

Now i have another shell script i.e `replacevariables.sh` and i want to execute the following command in my dockerfile.

`sh replacevariables.sh ${app_dir} dev`

How can i execute this command. It is a simple script which is basically going to replace some characters of files in `${app_dir}`. What can be the solution for this because when i see any kind of documentation they all suggest to run only one sh script.

Comment: Can you please try `CMD ["sh", "-c", "/opt/startup.sh ; replacevariables.sh ${app_dir} dev"]` syntax  also add base path to  /<dir>/replacevariables.sh in above syntax and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Docker [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) to support this.  Consider the following Dockerfile fragment:

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh replacevariables.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
# Same as above
CMD ["/opt/startup.sh"]
```

The `ENTRYPOINT` becomes the main container process, and [it gets passed the `CMD` as arguments](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  So your entrypoint can do the first-time setup, and then run the special shell command `exec "$@"` to replace itself with the command it was given.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
./replacevariables.sh "${app_dir}" dev
exec "$@"
```

Even if you're launching some alternate command in your container (`docker run --rm -it yourimage bash` to get a debugging shell, for example) this will only replace the "command" part, so `bash` becomes the `"$@"` in the script, and you still do the first-time setup before launching the shell.

The important caveats are that `ENTRYPOINT` *must* be the JSON-array form (`CMD` can be a bare string that gets wrapped in `/bin/sh -c`, but this setup breaks `ENTRYPOINT`) and you only get one `ENTRYPOINT`.  If you already have an `ENTRYPOINT` (many SO questions seem to like naming an interpreter there) move it into the start of `CMD` (`CMD ["python3", "./script.py"]`).