# Prepend command using docker-compose while maintaining Dockerfile CMD

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my Dockerfile I specify the `CMD`:

```
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/node", "server.js"]
```

However I am looking to prepend a command in my `docker-compose` that should be run **before** the above `CMD` but not override it. I.E. both commands should be executed.

Comment: I wrote up a recipe for this in [Run a simple shell script before running CMD command in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61887148/run-a-simple-shell-script-before-running-cmd-command-in-dockerfile), which involves adding an `ENTRYPOINT` wrapper to the image's Dockerfile; does that approach work for you?  What's the thing that you want to do in the Compose setup but not in the image itself?

Comment: [docker-compose insert an extra command upon container creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52576258/docker-compose-insert-an-extra-command-upon-container-creation) more directly matches your question but its answer is IMHO less flexible.

Answer (score 1):

The `command` tag in `docker-compose` always overrides the CMD.

So you can

```yaml
command: >
    bash -c "# The work you want to do
    && exec /user/local/bin/node server.js"
```

Or use a script (node or just shell script) in your `Dockerfile`.

```sh
if [ -n $FLAG ]; then
  # Do the processing
fi
exec /user/local/bin/node server.js
```

And in your `docker-compose.yml` you add the `FLAG` variable in the `environment` part.

```yaml
environment:
  FLAG: "yes"
```